# Invalid argument in template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying this simple `template template parameter` example:

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class Cont>
class Stack {
    //...
  private:
    Cont<T> s_;
};



int main(){
    Stack<int,std::vector> aStack1;

}
```

When I am trying to compile the compiler complains: `error type mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list...`

Do I have an error or maybe the problem is in the edition of my compiler? I am using g++ on Windows with Mingw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is becuase, despite having default arguments, std::vector has *2* template arguments (`template < class T, class Alloc = allocator<T> >`). The following code works just fine:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T, template <typename> class Cont>
class Stack {
    //...
  private:
    Cont<T> s_;
};

template <typename T>
using my_vector = std::vector<T>;


int main(){
    Stack<int,my_vector> aStack1;

}
```

Comment: As I understand another solution will be to use `template <typename T, template <typename ELEM, typename ALLOC=std::allocator<ELEM> > class Cont>`

Comment: @Avraam yes, though if your being that specific with the the input, you should probably just be using std::vector<T> in the class.